# testing mobile web app on iOS and Android

Tags: android, ios, mobile-website, aws-device-farm

I need to test a mobile web app on both iOS(Safari) and Android(Chrome). Do I need to create separate scripts depending on the OS or can logic be inserted in the same script (like getting OS name) and then executing the relevant flow.

Another aspect is that AWS device farm will be used for the testing. Hence what is best practice for writing the above-mentioned script

Answer (score 0):

Assuming both apps share the same UI it is certainly possible to use a single Appium test to test both Android and iOS; however, this can be tricky at times. Here is a good blog post discussing the issue.
[cross-platform-testing](https://blog.jayway.com/2016/06/30/cross-platform-testing-example-android-ios-using-appium/)

Scott